# why to use '$' in javascript variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen others do these things to create a dynamic table element or other HTML on a page:

```
var $myRow = $('#myRowContainer' + IDRow);
var $column = $('<div />', { 'class': 'col', 'css': { 'width': '30%' } }).appendTo($myRow);
$('<div />', { css: { 'text-align': 'left' } }).append($('<span />', { 'html': objDetails[0].message })).appendTo($column);`
```

I often create html stuff in javascript like:

```
 jQuery.each(mytable, function (i, obj) {
                    var newrow = ' <tr> ';
                    newrow += ' <td> ';
                    newrow += ' <span> ' + obj.ID + '</span>';
                    newrow += ' </td> ';
                    newrow += ' <td> ';
                    newrow += ' <span> ' + obj.PartNumber + ' </span>';
                    newrow += '</td>';
                    newrow += ' <td> ';
                    var name1 = 'txEI_';
                    var consecutive = obj.IDc;
                    var idLabelText = name1 + consecutive;
                    newrow += ' <input id="' + idLabelText + '" class="' + myCssClassToDetect + '" type="text" value="0" /> ';
                    newrow += ' </td> ';
                    newrow += ' </tr> ';
                    $("#tbDesglose").append(newrow);
                    //make spinner for new field
                    makeSpinner(idLabelText);
                });
```

What's the difference? Why choose one over another?

Answer (score 1):

When I see var prefixed with $ in javascript, it just usually means the variable is storing some element that is already wrapped in jQuery.

It's just a coding convention some people do.

Comment: And it's smart to differentiate semantically between a DOM node and a jQuery object wrapping a DOM node.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I get more clear with the creation of DOM elements using the JQuery object that wraps inside a DOM element. but still don't get clear with the $ before the variable, I think I will need some clearer example